# Is using class_replaceMethod to implement iOS4.x features in a iOS3.x runtime sane?

Tags: objective-c

I want to use some of the iOS 4.x things in iOS 3.x.    I know how to implement them, I assume my implementation is slower or might have more bugs then Apple's so I want to use Apple's any time it is available.

Is doing something like this sane:

```
@implementation NSDictionary (NSDictionary_4)

void compatability_method(Class class, SEL newer_version_selector, SEL compatability_selector) {
    Method existingMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, newer_version_selector);
    if (!existingMethod) {
        Method compatabilityMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, compatability_selector);
        class_replaceMethod(class, newer_version_selector, method_getImplementation(compatabilityMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(compatabilityMethod));
    }
}

+(void)load {
    if (self == [NSDictionary class]) {
        compatability_method(self, @selector(enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:), @selector(four_enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:));
    }
}

-(void)four_enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop))block {
    BOOL stop = false;

    for (id key in self) {
        block(key, [self objectForKey:key], &stop);
        if (stop) {
            break;
        }
    }
}


@end
```

If it is a bad idea, what would be better?

(if it is sane, but the code is a bit off, I would like to know that too...but I'm more interested to know if the entire idea is decent, or if this entire sort of construct should be avoided)

Comment: The saner way is using the older enumeration style! :)

Comment: @quixoto I really like the newer enumeration style when accessing the values otherwise I would have already used the for(id key in self) form.      If it helps, you could assume I'm talking about the UIView block animation calls though...

Comment: I was only being half-facetious. Since your question is inherently a subjective one, I'll answer subjectively: this isn't sane. If you need to target < 4.0, just use the APIs as given. Using the runtime to dynamically add "missing" functionality seems fragile and unobvious to me, which makes it hard to maintain when you find some buggy behavior down the road.